# cannot be used to initialize an entity of type const std::string *

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I have defined following constants in my header file:

```
class Example {

public:
    const static string* days_strs[];
    const static char* days_chars[];
};
```

And implemented them in example.cpp file:

```
    const static string* Example::days_strs[] = {"monday", "tuesday", ...};
    const static char* Example::days_chars[] = {"m", "t", ...};
```

Why do I get for

`days_str[]`

**"Error: a value "const char*" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "const std::string *"**?

Comment: You can't fill `const std::string *` with a string literal.

Comment: Try removing the `*`: `const static string Example::days_strs[] = {"monday", "tuesday", ...}` and similar for `days_chars`. For `days_chars`, use single quotes, e.g. `'m', 't', etc.`

Comment: So what's the best way and where to create an constant array days[] = {"Monday", "Tuesday", ...}; ?

Comment: Just use `const std::string`. No need for pointers at all. You probably want `const char` for the second as well since they're single characters.

Comment: Thank you @djikay but why is that different from char type? That's what confuses me...

Comment: Well, `string* Example::days_strs[]` is a static array of `string` pointers. What you want is an array of strings, not string pointers. Similarly for `days_chars`, you want an array of chars, not an array of char pointers.

Comment: `std::string` and c-strings are completely different beasts. BTW: It might make sense to save pointers to c-strings instead of `std::string`-objects here.

Comment: Thank you all on the answers! Sorry for stupid question. I'm new to c++ and specially this pointers...

Comment: @Xerath there are no stupid questions, at least that's what I think. Best of luck to you in your C++ journey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant the following

```
class Example {

public:
    const static string days_strs[];
    const static char* days_chars[];

};

//...

   const string Example::days_strs[] = {"monday", "tuesday", ...};
   const char* Example::days_chars[] = {"m", "t", ...};
```